# Can I use cycle plugin with image that change each week?

Tags: jquery, cycle, slide

I need make a slide with images that must change every week.

I have an php script that read a database where is the names of images and caption and titles, and create the div and send to the page the html.

My problem is that i don`t khow how use the cycle plugin in the div created by php.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please click the arrow next to the question if it helped you out.

Answer (score 0):

This jquery cycle plugin has tons of examples and is quite easy.  You place whatever content inside a div (or other html element) and the items inside get cycled.

You can review this site that has all of the information you need:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

Here is an example taken from their super basic demo http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/basic.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>JQuery Cycle Plugin - Basic Demo</title>
<style type="text/css">
.slideshow { height: 232px; width: 232px; margin: auto }
.slideshow img { padding: 15px; border: 1px solid #ccc; background-color: #eee; }
</style>
<!-- include jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- include Cycle plugin -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade' // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slideshow">
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
        <img src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/beach5.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```